# How can I stop windows opening under the LH menu bar?

Tags: 20.04, window, panel, menu-bar

Sometimes, not always, a window will open or expand, with no action on my part, such that it is under the left hand menu bar/panel.

If I'm lucky I can reduce/minimise the window then expand it and this fixes the issue, other times I have to close the application and reopen it.

How can I stop this happening in the first place?